# Why is vscode removing my spaces?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, editorconfig

I have an angular project generated using the angular-cli with the following extensions in my vscode:

Angular Language Service
Auto Import
Debugger for Chrome
EditorConfig for VS Code
TSLint

I have a problem where vscode is removing my spaces.  For example say I add the following spaces underneath the switch statement.  If I don't type a non space character, then within less than a second it will delete my spaces underneath the switch statement.  It's very annoying.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an .editorconfig file which has the following setting:

```
trim_trailing_whitespace = true
```

I also installed the EditorConfig for VS Code extension.  This will cause the annoying behavior of trimming trailing whitespace.  To fix this I just have to set this setting to:

```
trim_trailing_whitespace = false
```

Finally it's annoying to manually delete extra trailing whitespace so I can have a linter automatically fix this for me.  In my case I'm doing an angular2 development using the angular cli and I just need to run this for it automatically fix my trailing whitespace problems:

```
ng lint --fix
```

I'm assuming that there are going to be similar commands for plain javascript linting and typescript linting.